# Loading Weights - NoneType Found

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am working on an LSTM for a final project. I've been following TensorFlow's tutorial here: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/sequences/text_generation for most of it, especially for how to save and load the models. However, it's coming up with this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "D:\xxx\Documents\Class Coding\Artificial Intelligence\Shelley>\Writerbot.py", line 187, in 
>      restore_progress()
>
> File "D:\xxx\Documents\Class Coding\Artificial Intelligence\Shelley\Writerbot.py", line 141, in restore_progress
>
> shelley.load_weights(weights)
>
> File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\network.py", line 1508, in load_weights
>
> if _is_hdf5_filepath(filepath):
>
> File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\network.py", line 1648, in _is_hdf5_filepath
>
> return filepath.endswith('.h5') or filepath.endswith('.keras')
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'endswith'

And here is my code related to loading and restoring weights, as best as I can tell, since the rest of the error's coming from keras:

```
def create_shelley(vocab, embedding, numunits, batch):
    """This is what actually creates a neural network."""
    shelley = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab, embedding,
                              batch_input_shape=[batch, None]),
    lstm(numunits,
        return_sequences=True,
        recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform',
        stateful=True),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(vocab)
    ])
    return shelley

def train():
    """We create weight checkpoints as we train our neural network on files     fed into it."""
    checkpoints = 'D:\\xxx\\Documents\\Class Coding\\Artificial  Intelligence\\Shelley\\trainingcheckpoints'
    prefix = os.path.join(checkpoints, "ckpt_{epoch}")
    callback=tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
        filepath=prefix,
        save_weights_only=True)

    print(epochsteps)
    history = shelley.fit(botfeed.repeat(), epochs=epochs,    steps_per_epoch=epochsteps, callbacks=[callback])

def restore_progress():
    """Load the most recent weight checkpoint."""
    trainingcheckpoints = "D:\\Robin Pegau\\Documents\\Class Coding\\Artificial Intelligence\\Shelley\\trainingcheckpoints\\checkpoint"
    weights = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(trainingcheckpoints)
    shelley = create_shelley(vocab, embed, totalunits, batch = 1)
    shelley.load_weights(weights)
    shelley.build(tf.TensorShape([1, None]))

restore_progress()
```

There is a "checkpoint" file that has no filetype. There are also files that look like "ckpt_[x].index" and "ckpt_[x].data-00000-of-00001

Thank you all for your help in advance.

Comment: I can't see how the code relates to the traceback

Comment: seems like the code you put in the question is not related to the error you gave us.

Comment: I think I fixed it, I took off "checkpoint" at the end of trainingcheckpoints and switched it to ' instead of ".